# Perl Mechanize, making a script to login on a webpage

Tags: perl, mechanize

I'm making a script to automatically login on a webpage, it starts with this:

```
use HTTP::Cookies;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new;
my $agent      = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => $cookie_jar );

my $server_endpoint = "http://10.11.5.2/index.php";

$agent->post($server_endpoint,[tg => 'login', referer => 'index.php',login => 'login',sAuthType=>'LOL',nickname=>'admin',password=>'012345678',submit=>'Login']);

print "Set Cookie Jar?\n", $agent->cookie_jar->as_string, "\n";

print $agent->content;
```

And I get a page saying **"you are not logged in"**...but when I use the same credentials in the browser everything works.

So I retrieved the value of the cookie sent by the server (located in the *set-cookie* header of the response) with  `$agent->cookie_jar->as_string`, here it's **OV3176019645=3inkmpee0r5gpfm41c3iltvda1**.

THen I put it in the POST request before sending it, like the following:

```
use HTTP::Cookies;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new;
my $agent      = WWW::Mechanize->new( cookie_jar => $cookie_jar );

my $server_endpoint = "http://10.11.5.2/index.php";
$agent->add_header( Cookie => 'OV3176019645=osovm5u0vfc2dmkuo6bqn6hah1' );
$agent->post($server_endpoint,[tg => 'login', referer => 'index.php',login => 'login',sAuthType=>'LOL',nickname=>'admin',password=>'012345678',submit=>'Login']);


print $agent->content;
```

This time everything works...

So, my question is: how can I automatically get the value of the cookie given by the server before I send my request ?

Another problem also appears, it's that the server sends back a cookie with the following shape (in the *set-cookie* header):

```
Set-Cookie3: OV3176019645=3inkmpee0r5gpfm41c3iltvda1; path="/"; domain=10.11.5.2; path_spec; discard; version=0
```

And I just need the 1st item of this cookie (**OV3176019....**).

I hope I was clear in my explanations.

Thanks

Comment: Try fetching the page first, then submitting the login form. Normally you don't need to mess around with cookies and jars manually.

Comment: @melpomene I did what you said, $agent->get($server_endpoint), then $agent->post($server_endpoint,[post_values]), but still the same....

Comment: What does it do if you remove all mentions of the cookie jar from your code and let WWW::Mechanize handle it on its own completely? You can also use Mechanize to submit the actual form instead of doing a `->post`. Just do the `get`, then let it figure out which form it needs to submit.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks but I don't see what you mean by "let Mechanize figure out which form it needs to submit", when I submit the login page in my browser I can clearly see that it's a POST request (using Live HTTP Headers)

Comment: Yes, of course. But WWW::Mechanize has functionality built in for submitting forms. Try those instead of doing the work yourself. https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#FORM-METHODS

Comment: @simbabque It seems nice indeed

Comment: @simbabque A problem though, when trying to use set_field function, like this set_field( name => value), name can't be with special caracter "]", example: user[nickname]... what to do ?

Comment: Why not? I think you're not quoting correctly.